# How to remove the child added to the stackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the scrollView and a stackLayout in it. Adding the `View` dynamically to the stackLayout. I am getting the following exception when I am trying to remove the View added:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

My code is as following

```xml
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            x:Name="MessagesScrollView">
    <StackLayout Padding="7" x:Name="MessagesStackLayout"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Add the code behind is:

```cs
MessagesStackLayout.Children.Clear();
foreach (var chat in messagesList)
{
    MessagesStackLayout.Children.Add(new CustomViewCell(chat));
}
```

Comment: where did you do the operation  `MessagesStackLayout.Children.Clear();` and `MessagesStackLayout.Children.Add(new CustomViewCell(chat));` ? in a thread ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it is not running the code on MainThread try the following and see if that works for you:

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
  {
     MessagesStackLayout.Children.Add(new CustomViewCell(chat));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @G.hakim, but still I am getting the same exception

Comment: The thing is, initially there is no issue while adding the children. The exception arises when I am trying to add one more after some time, for example, Initially, there are 12 messages in a view now If I am trying to add the 13th message now the exception is occurring.

Comment: So first you add a bunch of views, then you remove them all and try again am i correct!?